# How to install Kdenlive on Kali Linux?

Tags: apt, kali-linux, repository, kdenlive

Until this moment, I have installed packages solely on Ubuntu. 
Now, I am trying Kali Linux,namely

```
uname -v
#1 SMP Debian 4.9.18-1kali1 (2017-04-04)
```

A friend, who unfortunately knows less about Linux than me, told me of his problem to install even basic Packages on another Debian distro, though this seems odd, since I heard, that the Repository of Debian is far more bigger than that from Ubuntu.

I tried

```
apt install kdenlive
apt install audacity
apt install blender
```

The fruitlessness of my striving made me modest and so I tried

```
apt install cowsay
```

But even this could not be installed, 
could you give me an advice how to deal with this?

Comment: If your friend isn't a professional security expert, why in the world would they be using Kali? I suggest you tell your friend to read http://docs.kali.org/introduction/should-i-use-kali-linux and to instead switch to a normal Linux distribution. Kali is a professional tool designed to be used by experts. It is not and should not be used as a regular every day operating system. That said, we can't help you if you don't tell us what happened when you tried this.

Comment: my friend does not use Kali, he uses Trisquel. The idiot, who installed Kali without having being a professional is me. I have installed it for sheer adventure and experience after I saw my 12 year old nephew using it, I thought "maybe you do not have to be an expert in quantuumchromodynamics to try it.  Why should not an expert use Kali?

Comment: @terdon I read your link, and I think the only reason for me not using it is explained in this part:In addition, misuse of security and penetration testing tools within a network, particularly without specific authorization, may cause irreparable damage and result in significant consequences, personal and/or legal. “Not understanding what you were doing” is not going to work as an excuse.     However, I am not interested in penetrating another persons system, I could simply enjoy the fun of penetrating myself

Comment: Heh, fair enough. Just as long as you know it's not supposed to be used as your everyday OS.

Comment: I did not know they are so serious about what is inside their repositories, this could be a problem with getting nvidia drivers, maybe

Comment: Well yes, of course. Why would you want or need nvidia drivers for Kali? This isn't an operating system, it;s a very specialized tool. If you're going to be installing NVIDIA on it there's no point in using it. If you want to play with Kali, set it up as a dual boot and only use it for pen-testing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `kdenlive` package is available on kali linux (`main` repo)

You should edit your [sources.list](http://docs.kali.org/general-use/kali-linux-sources-list-repositories) as follows:

```
deb http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling main contrib non-free
```

then run

```
apt update
apt upgrade
apt install kdenlive
```

Also you can install it through `snap`:

```
snap install --edge --force-dangerous --devmode kdenlive-devel
```

[Official docs](https://kdenlive.org/2016/10/kdenlive-packages-available-for-testing/)

To install [`audacity`](http://pkg.kali.org/pkg/audacity) and [`blender`](http://pkg.kali.org/pkg/blender) run the following ( after editing the sources.list):

```
apt install audacity blender
```

Comment: I can't install it in kali, becase **`kdenlive : Depends: kdenlive-data (= 17.08.3-2) but 1:0.9.10-dmo2 is to be installed`** can you help me?

Comment: @Milor123  Because your problem is different , It is better to ask a new question including the error message and the content of your `sources.list` and the content of  files under `/etc/apt/sources.list/d` .